# Python - How to filter out files that contain char at specific index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to filter out all files that doesn't contain "-" at index 82.
Sorry, real new to programming in general, any help is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a string slice:

```py
# assuming "files" is a list of file names
files = [f for f in files if f[81:82] == '-']
```

The above checks if the 82nd character be `-` or not.  If instead you want to check the 82nd *index*, then use:

```py
files = [f for f in files if f[82:83] == '-']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[fname for fname in list_of_filenames if fname[82:83] == '-']
```

will filter out any filenames in a list that dont contain `'-'` at index 82 ...

(but i think you want `fname[83:84]` since arrays are zero based... and presumably your text editor columns start at 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the below code directly for files present in your directory(without making a text list of the names if you wish)

```
import fnmatch 
import os 

#assuming there is -- can't come at any other position
pattern = '*--*.docx'

#specify directory path of files
files = os.listdir('') 
for name in files: 
    if(fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern)):
        print ('Filename:',name)
```